# Can i use 'require' instead of 'import' in 'fb react-create-app'?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I ask this coz of consistency in my coding.I learning parallel NodeJS and ReactJS and answer will be real helpfull for me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean create-react-app? I am not sure when you would need to import it?
However in general instead of `import a from 'b'` you can use `const a = require('b').default`

Comment: Thanks a lot the_cheff.I mean exactly create-react-app.

Answer (score 2):

`import [something] from '[someware]'` - is ES6 standard which you are and you want to be using in your react app, 
`requre('[someware]')` - is ES5 standard in Node.js. ES6 is not yet fully implemented in node however it will get there one day, so keep on using both as needed, no problem there.
If you really want full ES6 in your node.js apps you can use a transpiler like Babel etc. This [guide](https://hackernoon.com/quickstart-guide-to-using-es6-with-babel-node-and-intellij-a83670afbc49) will get you started.

Comment: Thanks,i will use both,require for NodeJS and import for reactJS.